# how to get Suggestion from JSON object just like JSONata when we search anything

Tags: javascript, json, search, filter, jsonata

I want to get Suggestions Just like JSONata when we search through ant json object, below i have provided example

```
const sourceData = {
      address: {
        city: "S Amsterdam",
        country: "Netherlands",
        line1: "Bijlmerplein 94",
        line2: "Amsterdamse Poort",
        postal_code: "1102 DA",
        state: "Noord Holland",
        newDeepTest: {
          deepTest: "deepTest Value"
        }
      },
      created: 1405637071,
      currency: "usd",
      description: "someone@example.com for Coderwall",
      email: "someone@example.com",
      name: "John Smith",
      phone: "0123456789"
    };
```

when i search through this JSON data as below input, i want desired output as suggestions

input - "add"

output - address.city, address.country and so on, as address is parent and its have child

input - "cit"

output - "...city" as it is child of address then add prefix ...

input - "new"

output - ...newDeepTest  , ...newDeepTest.deepTest -- as newDeepTest is child of address and deeptest is its children

just like JSONata. can anyone help me? what i have done so far is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-chaum-jbd7cm?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Could you explain what does "just like JSONata" mean?

Comment: i already added input for search and suggestion as output is like JSONata

Comment: JSONata is a query and transformation language for JSON data, I don't understand how is it related to the suggestions engine logic you're describing.